# jQueryUI radio button visible

Tags: jquery-ui, radio-button, jquery-ui-button

jQuery mobile leaves the radio button visible.  Is this possible with jQueryUI without too much effort? Users understand the functionality of a radio button, so I'd prefer to keep that visual recognition.

[image: jQuery Mobile Radio Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery

```
$("#radioSet").buttonset();
$("#radio1").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-check' });
$("#radio2").button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-check' });

$("#radioSet input[type=radio]").on("click", function () {
    $("#radioSet input[type=radio]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-check' });
        } else {
            $(this).button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-cancel' });
        }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="radioSet">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>
</div>
```